# Log in a user upon password reset?

Tags: login, password

During the typical WordPress password reset flow, this is what happens:

1. Click "Lost your password?" on /wp-login.php
2. Enter a valid email address to get a link to reset your password.
3. Enter the new password via that link, at a URL like /wp-login.php?action=rp&key=XYZ123
4. But you would have had to have copied the password or remembered it, because next you need to click Log in again and then enter your username & the new password.

Is there a way to skip #4, and once you submit the form in #3 just log the user in right then?